# Designing a Delayed Load Switch Circuit for Voltage Transfer on a PCB

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, switches, delay, remote-control

I am seeking guidance for the design of a circuit on a PCB board. The intended function of this circuit is to facilitate the transfer of a 24 V voltage from the input to the output through the utilization of a load switch (SIP32429DN ([datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/63939/sip32429.pdf)), 3 A maximum). This transfer should only occur when a designated button is pressed.

Upon releasing the button, my objective is to sustain the circuit's activity for an additional second before initiating closure. In other words, I aim to introduce a brief delay before the circuit deactivates, rather than an immediate cessation upon button release.

I have identified two components highlighted in red for potential use in this design: a capacitor and a diode. Could you please review my chosen approach and components to determine its correctness for achieving the specified functionality?
[image]

Comment: Do you already have the load switch? If yes, what is it?

Comment: @winny not yet, I need to choose one, I think the load switch is the best approach(minimum devices)

Comment: Sure, but _which one_? You can’t design a circuit to interface towards an unknown part.

Comment: @winny SIP32429DN , on/off= should be the enable connection

Comment: Excellent, now we are getting somewhere. Please edit that information into the question along with link to datasheet.

Comment: How exact do you need your 1 second to be? +-100 ms?

Comment: @winny +-100ms will be great

Comment: Great is not a requirement criteria, but if you _need_ +-100 ms, you will need fairly tight tolerances on your components and need to hand-tune the values as the internal pull-down is specified from 0.7 to 4.5 Mohm and only lower bound given on EN trigger. A loosing battle if you need to make more than a few. A better option would be an MCU or timer circuit made for the purpose.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in the part number and link to datasheet. For future reference, please include this in your questions.

Comment: @winny I want to prevent from using on MCU. I want to refine the requirement: allow a delay of 800ms with a delta of 200ms is also accepted

Comment: Feel free to hand-tune the values of R1, R2, C1 to your SIP32429DN in question or get yourself a timer IC. I highly recommend you use a simulator.

Comment: @winny could you recommend for me another solution that does not include MCU but includes some timer? if you think load switch isn't the good solution I would happy to hear that too.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here but here are 50 potential candidates in stock, all of them more expensive than an ATtiny4 at 44 cents: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/programmable-timers-and-oscillators/689?s=N4IgjCBcpgzAnFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG1wB2ADgDYxEixbaAGAFlpCMtgCY%2BsdtxABWVvFEi48SpWl9WgiD1Gj2YPiAC6RAA4AXKCADKBgE4BLAHYBzEAF8iAWi3QQqSBYCuhEuTEdB2CgA

Comment: I don't understand how timer could help me, maybe some regular FET instead the load switch ?

Comment: How will the FET do the 1 second timing?

Comment: @winny connect Rc delay to Fet

Comment: Then you’ll have the problems I described above. Please simulate and test it.